# Дана матрица F(7,7). Найти наименьшей элемент в каждом столбце. Вывести матрицу и найденные элементы. Помогите пожалуйста. где у меня ошибка?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

Дана матрица F(7,7). Найти наименьшей элемент в каждом столбце. Вывести матрицу и найденные элементы. Помогите пожалуйста. где у меня ошибка?

```
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
dataGridView1.RowCount = 7; // Кол-во строк
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 7; // Кол-во столбцов
int[,] a = new int[7, 7]; // Инициализируем массив
int i, j;

//Заполняем матрицу случайными числами
Random rand = new Random();
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
{
a[i, j] = rand.Next(-10, 10);
// Выводим матрицу в dataGridView1
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = a[i, j].ToString();
}
}

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
{
int min = int.MaxValue;
if (min > a[i, j])
{
min = a[i, j];
}
// выводим результат
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(min);
}
//автоширина
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
}
}
```

Comment: `Найти наименьшей элемент`, а вы пишете `int min = int.MinValue;` - вы планируете найти элемент, меньший, чем `int.MinValue` ?

Answer (score 1):

Цикл по столбцам должен быть внешним.
Вынесите начальное задание минимума вне цикла по строкам.
И для правильной работы оно должно быть заведомо большим.

```
for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
{
   int min = int.MaxValue;
   for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
   {
       if (min > a[i, j])
       {
            min = a[i, j];
        }
```